# Query Laravel many-to-many relationship based on AND not OR

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I've searched and searched and can't find the solution to this. I'm using Laravel 5.5.

I have a simple 3-table system set up that looks like this:

- **product** Table
- **option_items** Table
- **option_items_products** Table (pivot table)

**product** model *hasMany* **option_items**
**option_items** *belongsToMany* **product**

I can sync and save and all is good.

I can even return results that seem to have an "or" operator. Meaning... I can find all products that have **option_item.id** 4 OR **option_item.id** 5 OR **option_item.id** 8

What I'm looking to do is be able to filter the products based on option_item, so I should be able to somehow accomplish getting all products that have **option_item.id** 4 AND **option_item.id** 5 AND **option_item.id** 8

The results will be more specific, but should be more accurate.

Hoping someone can help with some direction on how to query like this. I'm learning laravel but just need a bump in the right direction.

Comment: i guess better you add your code also so it will help someone to check

Answer (score 0):

Try to use eloquent-relationships
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

something like this

```
Products::with(option_items)->whereHas('option_items', function ($q) {
            $q->where('id','==', 1);
        })->get();
```

get products using option items where Id of option item is 1;

Comment: The thing with this is that I need it to pull in a product that has (all of) multiple options. So it would need a product with option id 5, 6, and 7, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
$optionIds = [2,1];
$users = Product::whereHas('optionItems',function ($q) use ($option_ids){
     $q->whereIn('option_items.id',$optionIds);
})->get();
```

It suggests that you have relation like that in your `Product` model:

```
public function optionItems()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(OptionItem::class, 'option_items_products')
}
```

Comment: When I try to do this, I get `BadMethodCallException
Call to undefined method App\Product::whereHas()`

Comment: I do have this in my Product model: `public function option_items()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\OptionItem')
      ->withTimestamps();
      
}`

Comment: If it helps, I'm using a pivot table. My setup is similar to this example: http://www.easylaravelbook.com/blog/2016/04/06/introducing-laravel-many-to-many-relations/

Comment: @John if you have relation `option_items` in your `Product` model you should use the same for whereHas like `whereHas('option_items' ...`. Laravel doesn't convert it to camelCase

Comment: I got this to work, but since the sql code it generates has this: ``option_items.id` in ('1', '16'))` the "in" evaluates to true if option_items_id is 1 OR 16

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
   $idArray = array("1","2","3"...);
   $productList = Product::  
               //To check that records exists or not.              
                whereHas(
                'optionItems', function ($query)  use ($idArray){
                    $query->whereIn('id', $idArray);
                }
            )        
              //To fetch the matched records.
                ->with(
                    [
                        'optionItems' => function ($query) use ($idArray) {
                            $query->select('*')->whereIn('id', $idArray);
                        },
                    ]
                )
                ->get()
                ->toArray();
```

Comment: same issue as the other suggestion. When I try to do this, I get `BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method App\Product::whereHas()`

Comment: I got this to work, but since the sql code it generates has this:  ``option_items`.`id` in ('1', '16'))` the "in" evaluates to true if option_items_id is 1 OR 16